# How to run the command 'Distribute' on large product of multivariable polynomials without simplifying it

Tags: performance-tuning, simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation, built-in-symbols

I am new to Mathematica, so pardon if question is trivial. I am trying to expand (i.e multiply out the factors) an polynomial expression $d$,  with many factors, obtained as a result of taking determinant of a matrix $p$ with polynomial entries. When I run the command `Distribute[d]` it outputs the same input expression. I do not want to run command `Expand` since `Expand`, while multiplying the factors, also `Simplify` the expression in an iterative fashion  thus increasing the run time.  Is there a way to multiply out these factors in the expression $d$ without absolutely any simplification please? Here is the code:

```
k = 5;

mask = RandomInteger[1, {15, k}];

poszero = Position[mask, n_ /; n != 0];

posone = Position[mask, n_ /; n == 0];

n = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {15, k}];

n = ReplacePart[n, poszero -> 0];

m = Array[a, {15, k}];

m = ReplacePart[m, posone -> 0];

m = m + n 

d = Det[p]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by simplifying the expression.  What makes you think this is happening?  The determinant your computing must be huge (too big for my computer, it appears).  Even efficient operations are going to be slow.  Displaying the result make take even more time than computing it.

Comment: When you say `Distribute[p]` do you mean `Distribute[d]`? And would it be a problem to call `Det` repeatably, but only when the `a[_,_]` values are known?

Comment: @mikado : I have edited the code. I reduced the dimension of matrix as it makes computation of $d$ faster. As I run the code I see that $d$ is sum of product of many polynomial factors. I want to multiply out those factors and write $d$ as one polynomial without any brackets or simplification. Since `Expand[d]` takes a long time to execute(presumably because `Expand` internally executes `simplify` after `Distribute` the expression), I am looking for alternate ways to speed up expanding the expression $d$.

Comment: @Coolwater: Thanks for pointing it out, I corrected the error.